# Javascript - Password form is not submitting

Tags: javascript, html

Form is not submitting on enter. Maybe I'm missing something so need help of fellows or any advise/tips to find out the problem. I think the problem is in password field.  Thanks!

```
    <form onsubmit="login(); return false;">
        <p>
            Email*: <input type="text" id="email" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Password*: <input type="password" id="pass" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <span id="loginBut" onclick="login(); return false;" class="btn bold">
                Submit
            </span>
        </p>
    </form>


function login() {

    console.log('Inside login');
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post the code for your login() function.

Comment: You are returning false on the onsubmit event, so expecting the form to submit is a bit optimistic.

Comment: there is no action attribute in your form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be

```
<form id="myForm">
  <p>
    Email*: <input type="text" id="email"/>
  </p>

  <p>
    Password*: <input type="password" id="pass"/>
  </p>

  <p>
   <span id="loginBut" onclick="login();"
        class="btn bold">Submit </span>
  </p>
</form>
```

and your `login` function should look like,

```
function login(){
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

if you still want to use the span you can try adding this script.

```
document.getElementById('myForm').onkeypress = function(e){
  //enter has the keyCOde 13
  if (e.which == 13){
    document.forms[0].submit();

  }
};
```

Comment: Onclick is working fine. I want Form submit on enter.

Comment: why dont you just use `<input id="loginBut" type="submit" />` instead of  `<span id="loginBut" onclick="login(); return false;" class="btn bold">
                Submit
            </span>` ?

Comment: If I use input style is not applying.

Answer (score 1):

Just to repeat the appropriate response @adeneo already said in the comments, your form definition should be:

`onsubmit="return login()"`

And your `login` function should `return true` when you want the form to submit

If you `return false`, the form will not submit

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn bold" onclick="signup(); return false;">Submit </button>
```